# links to log files directly?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am using Cruise control.NET  and I just want to know if we can specify a
link which directly leads us to the log files in the webdash- baord
instead of the user clicking and navigating a long way in order to see
the log files.
So if anyone can share any idea where just a click on the link
specified in the mail could lead the user to check the log files
directly.

Please get back to me if the doubt mentioned is unclear.

Thanks and regards
Maddy

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're saying about the link.  Have you thought about just emailing the log files to them?

In your email publisher you can add log files and attachments to the email sent out.  You could attach the proper log file and save them the navigation if they need to look at it.

```
<xslFiles>
   <file>xsl\header.xsl</file>
   <file>xsl\compile.xsl</file>
   <file>xsl\unittests.xsl</file>
   <file>xsl\modifications.xsl</file>
</xslFiles>

<attachments>
    <file>C:\Data\AFile.txt</file>
    <file>Relative.txt</file>
</attachments>
```

Also, another solution would be to try sending the full report.  This defaults to false in the email publisher.  This might possibly send the exact information you were trying to see by looking at the log files.

```
<includeDetails>true</includeDetails>
```

For more information on the Email Publisher, go [here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Email+Publisher)